# FFI export of arguments of function type

Tags: haskell, marshalling, webassembly, ghc-asterius

I'd like to export a Haskell function that takes a function argument:

```
foreign export javascript "myFun" myFun :: (Int -> Int) -> Int
myFun :: (Int -> Int) -> Int
myFun f = f (f 0)
```

However, `ahc-link` complains that `Int -> Int` is not a valid parameter type for an FFI-exported function:

```
    • Unacceptable argument type in foreign declaration:
        ‘Int -> Int’ cannot be marshalled in a foreign call
    • When checking declaration:
        foreign export javascript "myFun" myFun :: (Int -> Int) -> Int
```

The other possibility would be to pass the function as a `JSVal`, but then I don't know how to cast that into something that I can apply on `Int`s on the Haskell side.